# Div to fit parent div height - where child is display:table

Tags: html, css, joomla, virtuemart

I am trying to make a responsive table for my products.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 desc-table">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6 desc-title-table"> <!-- display:table -->
                <span class="desc-title">Coverage:</span> <!-- display:table-cell -->
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <span class="desc-text">24sqm/Litre per coat</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

And this is the CSS

```
.desc-table{border:1px solid #4a4a4a;margin-bottom:5px;}
.desc-table .span6 {display:table;}
.desc-table span {display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;}
.desc-table > .row-fluid > .span6 {padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;margin-left:0px;}
.desc-title {font-weight: bold;}
.desc-title-table {background-color:#4a4a4a; color:#fff;}
```

The problem I am having is if the content in one div spills onto more than one line, the sibling div (span6) does not expand to the same height.

I have tried:

- height:100%;
- height: 100%; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;

The div is display:table so i can vertically align the text within it.
[Image of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSrV4.jpg)

My website is a Joomla! and Virtuemart website if that helps.

Comment: You need to make the ROW ``display:table` and the inner columns `display:table-cell`.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not clear as to what it is you're trying to accomplish, my guess is that you want the `.desc-title` div to take up the same height as the corresponding description div `.desc-text`.

In other words, you want to **imitate the display of vertically aligned table cells**, where both cells take up the same height as one another.

You're on the right track; you just need to refine your styles a bit.

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}
.wrapper {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: green;
  display: table;
}
.desc-title {
  color: #fff;
}
.desc-table .row-fluid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.desc-table .row-fluid > .span6 {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row-fluid > .span6:first-child {
  background: #4a4a4a;
}
.row-fluid > .span6:last-child {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 desc-table">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6 desc-title-table">
          <!-- display:table -->
          <span class="desc-title">Coverage:</span>
          <!-- display:table-cell -->
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <span class="desc-text">24sqm/Litre per coat</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6 desc-table">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6 desc-title-table">
          <!-- display:table -->
          <span class="desc-title">Drying Time:</span>
          <!-- display:table-cell -->
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <span class="desc-text">Approx. 8 – 10 hours in normal conditions.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Didn't work for my page. This is the page with my original code. http://www.flooringsales.co.uk/finishes/polyx-hardwax-oil-matt-sample-5ml-detail

Comment: @FlooringSales Here is what you need to get your stuff fixed, make sure it's appended after all other styles: http://pastebin.com/HzCbfcSN

Comment: @FlooringSales How did it go?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to try it yet, when I do I shall post my results.

Answer (score 0):

Actually sibling div will not expand automatically, to do that either you need to use JS or `style="white-space:no-wrap"` with the label/span to avoid wrapping.